# How could March 30th 2024 be followed by the 1st?

Tags: linux, bash, kernel, date, raspbian

I am in the EU zone +1 or when [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is on, +2. Now is Sunday 31.3.2024. This Sunday morning, we changed into DST, at 2→3 ([CET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time) → [CEST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Summer_Time)).

I have Linux servers in separate networks reporting monthly energy consumption at 23:58 of the last day of the month. They have worked perfectly for many years. Networks are up to 8 hours travel apart!

Each server has an [RTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) and syncs [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) regularly. There are many safeguards if anything is suspicious, and three core servers in each network constantly check against each other whether everything, including the time, is OK. Yes, I am paranoid. I tolerate no (0) bugs. My systems work perfectly stable for many years. Worked, sorry.

Last night, at 23:58 of March 30th, all of my Raspberry Pi servers decided that the March 30th is followed by the 1st of the next month! I verified 7 (seven) different and independent ways per each network, that everything did really occur at March 30th within the minute 23:58! Confirmation includes 9 separate devices ignoring DST, plus an external US and an EU mail provider.

At 23:58 of each day, my servers do a bash test that can apparently go wrong many ways:

```
(( $(date -d tomorrow +"%-d") == 1 )) && ZadnjiDanMjeseca=1 || ZadnjiDanMjeseca=""
```

I do not see any way for this test to go wrong! I hope I am wrong. At this moment at 31.3.2024. Everything works perfectly fine, and zdump is correct! (The following example appears misformatted for me. There must be four distinct rows shown.)

```
hwclock; date; date -d tomorrow +"%-d"
2024-03-31 19:22:23.311664+02:00
ned, 31.03.2024.  19:22:23 CEST
1
```

The only way I can explain this issue is: The Linux distribution I use, [Raspbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software), somehow has two separate kernel functions calculating time. One of them, sadly, missed the fact that this is a leap year! Ups!

But, if so, why should it be limited to this Raspberry Pi OS version and kernel? Hell, Microsoft failed to make Excel calculate leap years correctly!

Over this weekend, I have seen several institutions (banks, our national tax office...) in my country having date related issues and closing the shop, too, so it seems not to be limited to Raspbian.

This goes against me as a programmer, but, I can find no alternative explanation. Hopefully, I am wrong...

Before posting, I made a switch from 23:58 to the 00:03 on the 1st, and where I must log data at 23:58 of the last day of the month, I test by adding 300 seconds, not asking for +1 day. These solutions should work.

So it is not buried in the comments: As I never use such calculations, I made a basic error in expecting "tomorrow" actually means tomorrow! It doesn't make any sense to me; it means +1 day. So, I have expected these two commands produce the same output:

```
> date -d 'next tue'
uto,  2.04.2024.  00:00:00 CEST

> date -d 'tomorrow'
uto,  2.04.2024.  10:24:55 CEST
```

instead of having to type:

```
date -d "tomorrow 0"
```

Comment: Leap years affect the end of February, not of March...

Comment: That is only thing I can think of as a cause! February 29. affects all the days following it if one misses it! Well known Off by one!

Comment: Yes, but March 29, 30, and 31 would be equally shifted, so that wouldn’t explain this.

Comment: I just remembered that some countries switch DST at midnight. For them, adding 5 minutes at 23:58 would not work! In EU, we DST is at 02:00 and 03:00

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, I get:

```
# date -s '2024-03-30 23:58'; date -d tomorrow
Sat Mar 30 23:58:00 EET 2024
Mon Apr  1 00:58:00 EEST 2024
```

which isn't really surprising since 24 hours after 2024-03-30 23:58 it *is* 2024-04-01 00:58. Just that the latter is in daylight savings time.

[The manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html):

> Relative items adjust a date (or the current date if none) forward or backward. The effects of relative items accumulate.
> [...]
> More precise units are [...], ‘day’ worth 24 hours,
> [...]
> The string ‘tomorrow’ is worth one day in the future (equivalent to ‘day’),
> [...]
> When a relative item causes the resulting date to cross a boundary where the clocks were adjusted, typically for daylight saving time, the resulting date and time are adjusted accordingly.

The way to avoid issues like that is to ask for a time that's not close to midnight.

E.g. noon-ish usually falls on the right day:

```
# date -s '2024-03-30 23:58'; date -d '+12 hours'
Sat Mar 30 23:58:00 EET 2024
Sun Mar 31 12:58:00 EEST 2024
```

And this also seems to work:

```
# date -s '2024-03-30 23:58'; date -d '12:00 tomorrow'
Sat Mar 30 23:58:00 EET 2024
Sun Mar 31 12:00:00 EEST 2024
```

Comment: This actually makes sense and explains the problem! In the meantime, I changed code to activate to 00:03 on the 1st, expecting there can be no fault as there are no calculations involved!

Comment: “which isn't really surprising” — well, it is perhaps a little surprising that `tomorrow` (which is the same as `+ 1 day`) means “add 1 day = 24 hours = 86400 seconds to the clock”, and not “add 1 to the calendar date and keep the time intact”. The `month` and `year` unit do add 1 to the calendar element.

Comment: I got lost since I use epoch, and often in "DST ignoring" mode, mxising it sometimes with DST ignoring time and DST obeying times! Embarrassing, but I learned an important thing! Man, I hate DST. I never know if I sleep 1 hour longer or wake 1 hour earlier or if I am supposed to be hungry 1 hour later or earlier!

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', hum, but the same issue comes up with `month` and `year`. E.g. starting at 2024-03-15 23:58 EET and adding `+ 1 month` ends up at 2024-04-16 00:58 EEST. I guess the question is if (e.g.) EET and EEST are "the same" timezone or not, and if the tooling should helpfully take the offset change into account or not. But if it didn't take it into account, then what should `+ 4 hours` give when starting from that same date and time?

Comment: EET and EEST are the same timezone. The timezone name conveys both the timezone and whether DST is active. Regarding your month example: the way it works is that `date` calculates the number of calendar days, and then applies its day=24h rule to calculate the resulting time. Mixing calendar calculations with DST is tricky. @Pila For best robustness, first obtain the current (timezone-dependent) calendar date, then do calculations in UTC. In practice, doing day calculations for midday mostly works (only failing edge cases when a locale changes timezones, which is very uncommon).

Comment: I just edited what I did. I believe these will hold water. In my example, in log, I prefer the last day of the month. When the system sends me the e-mail, I do not mind it being on the 1st. at 00:03

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', so, I don't see a fundamental difference between `+1 day` and `+1 month`, then. Nor really the difference between adding 24h vs. adding one to the calendar date, since after all days are 24 h long.

Comment: @ilkkachu The difference is that `day` is a fixed number of a smaller unit, whereas `month` and `year` are not. `+1 month` is the same day-of-month in the next calendar month, with overflow if that day-month-year does not exist. For example `+1 month` is equivalent to `+31` days in January, to `+28 days` in February of a non-leap year, etc.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', that's true, but it would appear to me that's orthogonal to the issue of how it behaves at the DST change. Perhaps I just parsed your original comment wrong.